# Content Under Sidebar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am relatively novice when it comes to Bootstrap. I want content to be stretched full width under the right content block. I have attached a screencast which should help show what I am trying to do. I have tried using offset on the right block, but it doesn't do what I want. Is there a way that Bootstrap handles this, or is this something that has to be custom written?

http://screencast.com/t/ZxJGOBEy

Here is my code (which isn't much):

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-8">

              <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>

              <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>

              <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200" />
              <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you have now is two side-by-side columns. The text from `.col-md-8` can never overlap into the other column because they're each their own individual boxes, their own domains. To get the effect you're looking for, you need to introduce the div wrapping around your images into the div wrapping around the text and add `.pull-right` to it (this is one of [Bootstrap's helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) and forces the div to float to the right), e.g. :

```
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200" />
    </div>
```

You can see the result here:  http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/zqwpgg?editors=1000